# C# adding to a list when two out of two radios are unchecked

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and more so c#, on and off have been picking it at. Trying to learn by doing very basic projects in my spare time and am trying to figure out why I am not getting a result when both radios out of two are unchecked. The simple idea is if both radios are unchecked write a simple string to a list. Of course I can easily see both or one or the other and get two written indexes to the list, one for each. I am trying to see why I can't get just one list add if both are unchecked:

```cs
foreach (var child in children)
            {
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    UserText.Add("TXT BOX11");
                }

                if (child.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
                {
                    if (((((RadioButton)child).Name == "Radio1") && ((RadioButton)child).IsChecked == false)
 && ((((RadioButton)child).Name == "Radio2") && ((RadioButton)child).IsChecked == false))
                    {
                        UserText.Add("Pickles");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Instead of `child.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton)` we now write `child is RadioButton`. You can even write `child is RadioButton rb` where `rb` will be the RadioButton cast of your child, which you can then use in the scope so that you don't need to cast it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only ever checking the current child. Since your condition is both `((RadioButton)child).Name == "Radio1"` and `((RadioButton)child).Name == "Radio2"` it will never be true.

You might want to use the [CheckedChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=net-5.0) instead or just access the radiobuttons through their variables. Probably named something like `radioButton1` and `radioButton2`.

Lastly, if it has to be within the `foreach` loop you could set an external variable to keep track.

```cs
bool otherButton = false;
foreach (var child in children)
{
  // textbox code

  if(child is RadioButton rbtn && rbtn.Name == "Radio1" && rbtn.IsChecked == false)
  {
    if(otherButton)
      UserText.Add("Pickles");
    else
      otherButton = true;
  }
  if(child is RadioButton rbtn && rbtn.Name == "Radio2" && rbtn.IsChecked == false)
  {
    if(otherButton)
      UserText.Add("Pickles");
    else
      otherButton = true;
  }
}
```